# Why was question closed? It follows suggestions

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/184030/reduce-suds-created-from-washing-machine-rinsing) recently, and it was closed for the following reasons: [image]

It says: `Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve`.

My question: why was it closed? I'm not asking for product or service recommendations and *I describe my situation and the specific problem I'm trying to solve*. It also received two upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

The most pointed reason that the question was closed is summarized in a comment as "This is an appliance usage question and not about home improvement".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think is an XY problem that wasn't clearly stated. One of the answers actually "gets" it:

> But it seems the real problem you're having is the soapy water backing up into the first floor dishwasher.

I think that better than a Close (which was not "wrong", just missed the point, IMHO) would have been to Edit the question to change it a bit (yes *change* it, that isn't against the rules and could always be reverted if OP doesn't like it) from an "appliance" problem (off-topic) to a plumbing problem (on-topic).